# Define npm Proxy Windows

Tags: node.js, proxy

I have seen several posts on this, but most likely nothing seems to work. I tried to set the npm proxy. What ping wpad - commands are not working so i have tried different ways to find out, what proxy i am using.

What I've tried so far (everything also for https-Proxy):

```
http://proxyname:port
http://proxyname.DNS-Suffix:port
http://DNS-Suffix.proxyname:port
http://Username:Password@DNS-Suffix.proxyname:port
http://Username:Password@proxyname.DNS-Suffix:port
http://"Username:Password"@proxyname:port
http://"Domain\Username:Password"@DNS-Suffix:port
http://DNS-Suffix:port
```

and some other stuff.
I got the proxyname and the port from my manual configuration in Windows. going for  chrome://net-internals/#proxy gives me the same result as my config, so i can assume that this is the right adress&port combination.

```
netsh winhttp show proxy
```

says that i have direct access (For whatever reason), but also setting no proxy did not work. DNS-Suffix is what i got from ipconfig /all. It feels kinda sad to ask for help considering what i am trying to do (setting a proxy config), but i have no idea what else i should do.

Answer (score 0):

First check if proxy has been set up for npm using `npm get proxy`
next set proxy using `npm set proxy https://porxy.ip:port`

Comment: Thats what i tried, i checked with get proxy after setting it and he set it properly. When configuring proxy in Windows you can set it manually and say "Adress" and "Port". Since this config works, i can assume, that i can use exactly that Adress for proxy.ip and port = port, am i right? So if my proxy is named "foo" and my port is x, i can say     

    npm set proxy http://foo:x     and if i need credentials i would say   http://Username:Password@foo:x       or did i missunderstand that point?

Comment: Try without the username and password my corporate proxy doesn't require the username and password, maybe same for you.

Comment: I tried and he gave me a 407-Error:

    Error Code: 407 Proxy Authentication Required. Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.

Comment: Although I am trying the config with my credentials, it shows me

<LI id=L_default_12>IP Address: %IP%
npm ERR! <LI id=L_default_13>Date: 25.07.2017 14:08:15 [GMT]
npm ERR! <LI id=L_default_14>Server: XXX.XXX.XXX
npm ERR! <LI id=L_default_15>Source: proxy

Can i use that information for something? Like changing some settings? The credentials are set in the right way, i already checked that.

Comment: check if works with `npm config set strict-ssl false`